# Check for folder in path and remove remainder of url

Tags: php

I have two paths that I need to strip back to the Views folder and then check if a file exists within that folder.

Views/[Controller}/{Action}/{ID}

Areas/Views/[Controller}/{Action}/{ID}

I am looking for a way to remove from the url everything to the right of Views/

Comment: what do you mean remove?

Comment: And what do you know about the path? Where/how is it entered or what could it contain?

Comment: I want to know if the view requested is in Views or Areas/Views I just want the first part of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of http://php.net/substr and http://php.net/function.strpos

```
$url = substr( $url, 0, strpos($url, "Views/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
$url = 'Areas/Views/[Controller}/{Action}/{ID}';
$segmentedUrl = explode('/',$url);
$viewsPosition = array_search('Views', $segmentedUrl);
$leftPart = array_slice($segmentedUrl, 0, $viewsPosition+1);
var_dump($leftPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Path{

    protected $originalPath;
    protected $path; // only this path gets manipulated for method chaining reasons

    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->originalPath = $path;
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function getPartial($partial)
    {
        if(!isset($this->originalPath))
            throw new Exception('No Path set');

        // Get the position of partial in our path
        $rawPos = strpos($this->path, $partial);
        if($rawPos === false)
        {
            throw new Exception('The Partial: '.$partial. 'was not found within the path');
        }
        else
        {
            // If we found the partial let's add the length of the given
            // string to figure the actual position 
            $pos = $rawPos + strlen($partial);
            $this->path = substr($this->path, 0, $pos);
            return $this;
        }
    }

    public function find($file)
    {
        $path = $this->path;
        $this->rewindPath();

        if(is_file($path . '/' . $file))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    protected function rewindPath()
    {
        $this->path = $this->originalPath;
    }



}

// Instantiate Class
$path = new Path();

$path->setPath('Views/[Controller}/{Action}/{ID}');

var_dump($path->getPartial('Views')->find('test.txt'));

$path->setPath('Test/Views/[Controller}/{Action}/{ID}');

var_dump($path->getPartial('Views')->find('test.txt'));


?>
```

Altough the question is already answered I also wanted show you an OO-approach. Paths can be set dynamically and you can search files there using method chaining. It's just a blueprint so you get the basic Idea.

Happy Coding!